# Android spinners and scroll view

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` which has several `spinners` and above `spinners` there are `Textviews`. The last two `Spinners` are dependent on each others value. I have used a `ScrollView`. Now when I select one `Spinner` it changes the value of other. But my `ScrollView` goes up. How do I stop the `ScrollView` from scrolling?

Comment: You have to share your code.

Answer (score 2):

In your android manifest file, you have to add this tag along with your activity .

Tag-**android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"**

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Ansd sorry not text views.above there are Edittexts